# introduce new attribute to laravel collection object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to introduce a new field/attribute in the following laravel collection object. As you can see, I have fields like project, bidamount, awarddate etc .... I want to add another new field 'paid' for every items in the collection. How can I do that?

The collection is a result of hasMany relationship.

```
Collection {#233 ▼
#items: array:20 [▼
0 => Project {#234 ▼
  #table: "projects"
  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #original: array:11 [▼
    "id" => "15348"
    "project" => "Construction of blah blah blah"
    "bidamount" => "36830525"
    "awarddate" => "2012-08-15"
    "completedate" => "2013-12-31"
    "levyamount" => "55246"
    "fkcdb" => "1656"
    "fkfile" => "0"
    "fkclient" => "0"
    "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
}
1 => Project {#235 ▶}
2 => Project {#236 ▶}
3 => Project {#237 ▶}
4 => Project {#238 ▶}
5 => Project {#239 ▶}
6 => Project {#240 ▶}
```

Comment: Do we have to assume you already tried the laravel documentation here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#creating-columns but it wasn't useful to you for some reason? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're working with an *hasMany* relationship as you said, you don't need to work on the resulting collection. Instead, you could add a simple field to your "projects" table using the Schema Builder and an update migration.

Otherwise, if you don't want to add a new field to the table, you can always add a new **accessor** to your *Project* model.

```
...

class Project extends Model
{

    ...

    public function getPaidAttribute($value)
    {
        // example: write your logic here and put it in $value...
        return $value;
    }

    ...
}
```

More info here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Work with collections only in more advanced situations. Hope it was useful.

Oh, and more info about working with custom collections here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections#custom-collections

Comment: Thank you @user1823151. I didn't want to add the field in the table itself as the created attributes are for temporary purpose just to display some data. So, tried with the accessors and mutators and worked like charm.